# Creating Primary Key across Multiple Access Tables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have recently imported over 40 excel files into Access, but now I want to add a PK to each.

I have the following code, but it doesn't go past the db.execute line, I keep getting error 3291 syntax error in CREATE INDEX statement.  It looks ok but not sure why this is happening?

```
Public Sub AddPrimaryKey()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim td As DAO.TableDef



Set db = CurrentDb()

    For Each td In db.TableDefs

    If Left(td.Name, 6) = "REPORT" Then

    db.Execute "CREATE INDEX Employee No ON td.Name (Employee No) WITH PRIMARY"


    End If

Next td


End Sub
```

Comment: If Employee No is the name of a single column you should quote it

Answer (score 1):

Seems the field name includes a space, so bracket it.

Add the *value* of `td.Name` into the string.

```sql
db.Execute "CREATE INDEX [Employee No] ON " & td.Name & _
    " ([Employee No]) WITH PRIMARY"
```